# Cassandra Migration Library in Java

Tags: java, cassandra, migration, schema

I have created a Spring Boot microservice which runs aggregation on a stream of data and writes it into various Cassandra tables. I am looking for a java library similar to Flyway which will migrate Cassandra schema with the existence of a script in a resource folder. Does anyone have any recommendations, preferably for a library which you personally have used in production?

Comment: maybe you could try [liquibase extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cassandra)

Comment: and maybe [pillar](https://github.com/comeara/pillar)

Answer (score 0):

I used [builtamont](https://github.com/builtamont-oss/cassandra-migration/wiki):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.builtamont</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-migration</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

migration in code:

```
import com.builtamont.cassandra.migration.CassandraMigration;
import com.builtamont.cassandra.migration.api.configuration.KeyspaceConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

class CassandraDataSourceMigration implements InitializingBean {
    private final String ip;
    private final String clusterName;
    private final Integer port;
    private final String keyspaceName;
    private final String migrationsPath;

    public CassandraDataSourceMigration(String ip, String clusterName, Integer port, String keyspaceName, String migrationsPath) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.clusterName = clusterName;
        this.port = port;
        this.keyspaceName = keyspaceName;
        this.migrationsPath = migrationsPath;
    }

    // getters/setters

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        final KeyspaceConfiguration keyspaceConfig = new KeyspaceConfiguration();
        keyspaceConfig.setName(keyspaceName);
        keyspaceConfig.getClusterConfig().setContactpoints(new String[]{ip});
        if (port != null) {
            keyspaceConfig.getClusterConfig().setPort(port);
        }

        final CassandraMigration migrationProcessor = new CassandraMigration();
        migrationProcessor.setLocations(new String[]{migrationsPath});
        migrationProcessor.setKeyspaceConfig(keyspaceConfig);
        migrationProcessor.migrate();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
cassandra.ip=127.0.0.1
cassandra.cluster=My cluster
cassandra.keyspace=saya
cassandra.migration=classpath:db/migration
cassandra.port=9042
```

And the migration script is under resources/db/migration V1_0__Init_table.cql